# How to implement a child of a class in a separate library namespace using Caliburn Micro in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, namespaces, caliburn.micro

I've created a class called `Character` in a namespace SFLib
My actual project is in  seperate namespace. I want to create class that inherits from `Character` in my Models folder.
How can I make that work?

Comment: Are you saying you want to write a class `namespace Models { public class SomeClass : SFLib.Charater { /* methods, properties, etc. */ } }`? Or did you already do that, and you want to create an instance of it?

Comment: Add a reference to the assembly containing `Character`, and then add a reference to the namespace containing `Character` in the class that is to inherit from `Character`.  Then, add your inheritance.

Comment: "Make that work." Can you be more specific? What have you tried? Please post the code that is giving you problems.

Comment: Sorry I was at the playground with my kid when I was writing this.  Visual Studio was giving me an error about inheriting from a class in a different namespace and I tried a using statement and call from the specified namespace and it still wasn't having it.  Now its working magically so I don't know what I was doing wrong before...  Thanks anyway! :)